# How can the row and column labels of a Microsoft Reporting matrix be set?

Tags: reporting, rdlc

I have a simple matrix control on my report, and the data shows up like I expect, except without labels.

How can I get the labels to appear with the values I want (not necessarily the name of the data element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by highlighting the cell where the data is accumulated, it is possible to right click and select 'Insert Static Row' or 'Insert Static Column'.

Once the static row or column is created, it can be used as a label.